# How do I pass an integer through methods for calculations?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to create a program where the user can input 2 numbers, then a menu is displayed where the user can choose one of five options.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuProg
{
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {  
  int iNum1;        //Holds user input number 1
  int iNum2;        //Holds user input number 2
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); //Holds user input from keyboard
  int iMenu;
  
  System.out.print ("\n\nPress ENTER to continue");
  kb.nextLine();
  
  System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
  iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
  System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
  iNum2 = kb.nextInt();
  
  iMenu = menu();
 }

 public static int menu()
 {
  Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
  int iSelection;
  System.out.println("\n\t M E N U ");
  System.out.println("\n1>Sum up two integers" +
   "\n2>Find the difference of two integers" +
   "\n3>Find the average of two integers" +
   "\n4>Find the product of two integers" +
   "\n5>Find the quotient of two integers");
  iSelection = kb.nextInt();
  
  switch (iSelection)
  {
   case 1: 
    sumTwoNumbers();
    break;
   case 2:
    subTwoNumbers();
    break;
   case 3:
    avgTwoNumbers();
    break;
   case 4:
    multiTwoNumbers();
    break; 
   case 5:
    divTwoNumbers();
  }
  return iSelection;
 }
 public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
 {
  int iNum1;
  int iNum2;
  int iSum;
  
  iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
  return iSum;
 }
 public static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
 {
  int iNum1;
  int iNum2;
  int iSub;
  
  iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
  return iSub;
 }
 public static int avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
 {
  int iNum1;
  int iNum2;
  int iAvg;
  
  iAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
  return iAvg;
 }
 public static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
 {
  int iNum1;
  int iNum2;
  int iMulti;
  
  iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
  return iMulti;
 }
 public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
 {
  int iNum1;
  int iNum2;
  int iDiv;
  
  iDiv = iNum1/iNum2;
  return iDiv;

    }
```

I'm getting 32 errors, but mostly they have to do with expected identifiers, illegal start of types, and a lot of class, interface, or enum expected.  My main question is how would I pass the user inputted integers from my main through to my other methods for calculations?  If i could get that solved, i'm sure i can figure out the other errors. Thanks in advance.

```js
MenuProg.java:82: error: ')' expected
 public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
                                                     ^
MenuProg.java:82: error: illegal start of type
 public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
                                                           ^
MenuProg.java:82: error: <identifier> expected
 public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
                                                            ^
MenuProg.java:83: error: ';' expected
 {
  ^
MenuProg.java:84: error: <identifier> expected
  int iNum1;
           ^
MenuProg.java:88: error: <identifier> expected
  iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
      ^
Menu.java:89: error: illegal start of type
  return iSum;
  ^
MenuProg.java:89: error: ';' expected
  return iSum;

MenuProg.java:91: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
               ^
MenuProg.java:94: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:95: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iSub;
  ^
MenuProg.java:97: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:98: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  return iSub;

MenuProg.java:99: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
MenuProg.java:100: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static int avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
               ^
MenuProg.java:103: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:104: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iAvg;
  ^
MenuProg.java:106: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  iAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:107: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  return iAvg;
  ^
MenuProg.java:108: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
MenuProg.java:109: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
               ^
MenuProg.java:112: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:113: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iMulti;
  ^
MenuProg.java:115: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:116: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  return iMulti;
  ^
Proj2.java:117: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
MenuProg.java:118: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param)
               ^
MenuProg.java:121: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:122: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  int iDiv;
  ^
MenuProg.java:124: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  iDiv = iNum1/iNum2;
  ^
MenuProg.java:125: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  return iDiv;
  ^
MenuProg.java:126: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 }
 ^
        ^
```

Comment: What do you think the extra `param` argument does?

Comment: Why post those errors if they are unrelated to the questio?

Comment: Remove `param` from everything, first of all. That'll fix most of your issues. Then call `int result = sumTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);` in your main method to get the value.

Comment: Have you used an (free) IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ? These marks your mistakes without delay.

Comment: I was thinking adding 'param' there would pass the inputted integer from my main throughout the methods, I guess I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way

```
public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2 param){} 
//you cannot have a space in variable name
```

either it should be

```
public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2,int param){}
```

or

```
public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2param){}
```

Or As I dont see any use of *param* just remove it

```
public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have serious syntax issues, but the general idea of your program is actually pretty sound.
Syntax/minor things:
1.) look up `System.out.println()`, it adds a newline after whatever it prints.

2.) parameters/arguments for a method or function:

```
public static int funcName(int num1, int num2) {
     num1 = 2 + 3;
     num1 = num1 + num2;
     int result = num1 * num2;
     return result;
}
```

Notice how the parameters for the function look like `funcName(int num1, int num2)`, and then in the function those parameters have already been declared. You don't do `int num1;` in the function, you can just jump into using `num1 =` whatever. You do need to declare new, non-parameter variables in the function though, such as `int result` in this case.

3.) calling a function:

```
int x = 32;
int y = 15;
int functionResult = funcName(x, y);
// to print functionResult: System.out.print(functionResult); or print it within the function somewhere
```